# how to read html data from another page using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is the url "users/1/providers/1/check" to a page containing the following html

```
<select id="document1" class="form-control">
        <option th:value="0" >Select a document you want to share</option>
        <option th:each="document : ${documents}" th:value="${document.id}" th:text="${document.name}">[name]</option>
</select>
```

on this url "/users/1/providers/1/documents/1/consents/new: i want to access the data in html from "users/1/providers/1/check"

```
<select id="provider" name="provider" class="form-control" th:onchange="'javascript:showPIIDoc(this.value);'">
                                                    <option th:value="0" >Select a Service Provider</option>
                                                    <option th:each="provider : ${user.providers}"  name="name"  th:value="${user.id} +','+ ${provider.id}" th:text="${provider.name}" >[name]</option>
                                                </select>
```

using ajax how will i do it. I am using spring mvc

```
function showPIIDoc(doc)
{
    var split = doc.split(",");
    var userId = split[0];
    var providerId = split[1];
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '/users/'+ userId +'/providers/' + providerId + '/check',
        success: function(html){
            //Create jQuery object from the response HTML.
            var $response=$(data);

            //Query the jQuery object for the values
            var oneval = $response.filter('#document1').text();
            alert(oneval);
        }
    });
    });

}
```

Please guide me

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: I cant see any data in the alert! I think there is some problem in the ajax function.

Comment: try to change it to: `var $response=$(html);`

Comment: It did'nt work. still same problem.

Comment: how to check if the url is really accessed in the ajax function? @PabloMatíasGomez

Comment: try `console.log(html)` to see the response in the console and post it if you can.

Comment: You could use the Developer Tools to see the ajax response in the Network section.

Comment: I cant see any console logs or any action on network onchanging in select statement

Comment: the showPIIDoc(doc) is being called successfully but there is issue is ajax function. I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: Now, on the Network I am getting the url to be 200 in the ajax. The problem i solved. It was the problem with the url in the ajax.